# Return a boolean value from MySQL for using it in function as parameter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox, boolean

I'm building a simple user registration and information update forms which have a lot of checkboxes with CodeIgniter. I store the values of checkboxes as `1` (if checked) and `0` (if not checked) in MySQL database under the `tinyint(1)` fields.
So in user update form, I have to set default values which are return from these MySQL fields. On the other hand, the data shouldn't lost if the form validation isn't passed. Because of that, I need to use [set_checkbox](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) function of CI with third parameter, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_field" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('my_field', '1', $returned_boolean_value); ?> >
```

But it doesn't work, because my MySQL query doesn't return boolean value for variable `$returned_boolean_value`. It returns `0` or `1` as a string.
So the PHP query becomes something like this:

```
set_checkbox('my_field', '1', '1');
```

but it must be something like this:

```
set_checkbox('my_field', '1', TRUE);
```

My question is how can I set this third boolean parameter of set_checkbox with the data which is return from database?

I also looked throw the relevant questions, but found nothing about it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast to boolean

```
<?php echo set_checkbox('my_field', '1', (boolean) $returned_boolean_value); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using C++ style if/else

```
set_checkbox('my_field', '1', $returned_boolean_value ? TRUE : FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the good old double negation, or string comparison

http://codepad.org/Y7W0WWau

```
set_checkbox('my_field', '1', !! $string_0_or_1 );
set_checkbox('my_field', '1', $string_0_or_1 == '1' );
```

Comment: like mark shows you typecast the result, or try set the db fieldtype to boolean

Comment: Yes, that is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo set_checkbox('my_field', '1', (int) $returned_boolean_value); ?> 
<?php echo set_checkbox('my_field', '1', intval($returned_boolean_value)); ?> 
<?php echo set_checkbox('my_field', '1', (bool)$returned_boolean_value); ?> 
<?php echo set_checkbox('my_field', '1', $returned_boolean_value=='1'?true:false); ?>
```

You can use one of the above...